# HttpGet - Enclosing parameters in quotation marks

Tags: java, httpclient, urlencode, url-encoding, http-get

I'm working on an Android app that connects to .NET webservices. I use the Apache `HttpClient` to connect using the `HttpGet` method. The method that makes the actual call has the following code:

```
public static String httpGet(String methodName, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    String methodURL = BASE_URL + "/"+methodName;
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(methodURL+"?"+URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "UTF-8"));
```

So I take a `List<NameValuePair>` object and make the whole get URL from it. For some reason, the webservice does not accept the value parameters unless they are enclosed in quotation marks.

Is there a way to get the parameters enclosed in quotes without have to manually add the `"\""` to each and every parameter in the calls...?

Comment: Are the .NET web services a WSDL/SOAP services?
In that case, I suggest to use the KSOAP2 java library for Android instead of using directly an Apache `HttpClient`

Comment: Nah... I'm using Json. Although SOAP is also supported. I reckon maybe the porting between service types is what caused this weird requirement in the first place. Maybe they were originally SOAP and they added Json but didn't convert everything all the way through or something like that. Anyways, I'll just go with the helper method. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't change the resolution of the Web Service on the server side, you could have a helper method that would do just that, add the quotation marks. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the NVPs you already have--it's a few lines of code. There's no option to do this automatically, since it's a relatively unusual requirement.